# How to add data in openTSDB through java using tCollector

Tags: java, python, hadoop, hbase, opentsdb

My goal is to insert data into TSDB directly through java code, for which, I tried creating the executable jar which was printing data to STDOUT. Then I wrote collector to run this jar and put it inside `tcollector/collectors/0`. Finally, I tried executing the collector in two ways, one in shell script and the other in python.

Python Collector:

```py
def main():
    while True:
        os.system("java -jar ./TCollectorTSDB.jar")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(COLLECTION_INTERVAL)    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.stdin.close()
    sys.exit(main())
```

The above collector was working perfectly fine, but when I tried to run the same jar from shell script the Collector was not picking the shell script.

Shell script collector:

```
java -jar "./TCollectorTSDB.jar"
```

Do I have to configure something, to register this collector? 
If we have to insert data through Java which is the best way to do the same with Collector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tcollector doesn't care whether the collector you write is in Python or a shell script or what.  As long as you put the collector in `tcollector/collectors/0` it should be picked up automatically.  If it is not, then check that your shell script is executable (`chmod a+x`) and that it starts with a shebang (`#!/bin/sh` for example).